# Is it possible to do HTML5 drag and drop in the Android browser?

Tags: android, html, browser, drag-and-drop

I tried to implement a simple drag and drop in the Android browser with HTML5. When I try to drag an object only the screen scrolls and I cant drag anything in it. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a link that shows compatibility tables for support of HTML5, CSS3, SVG in desktop and mobile browsers
http://caniuse.com/#agents=mobile

Comment: and if you are too lazy to open that link, the short answer is NO, you can't do that yet.

Comment: well, it is hard to tell if you can override the object interpretation in your browser.. If it is a picture, say, you could inject js into WebView that will remove this picture, after you could download this picture using UrlConnection and insert it into a text if, of course, you have a combination of pictures and text. And in this case you can make your picture to react on drag and drop actions... P.S. you make this picture visible over WebView as a separate ImageView component

Comment: actually this is not the answer. you should come out with better answer