# Html5 Drag and drop in Android

Tags: android, html

I tried to implement a simple drag and drop in the Android browser with HTML5. When I try to drag an object only the screen scrolls and I cant drag anything in it. Is there any way to do this?

HTML is here :

```
 For drag:   

<div id="an-obj-12" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" dropzone="copy">42a</div>
<div id="an-obj-13"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" dropzone="copy">4a</div>
<div id="an-obj-14"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" dropzone="copy">14</div>

For drop:

<div id="an-obj-7" ondrop="drop(event,'12a^2')" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="an-obj-8" ondrop="drop(event,'42a')" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="an-obj-9" ondrop="drop(event,'4a')" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

Comment: Its not supported in Android.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324789/is-it-possible-to-do-html5-drag-and-drop-in-the-android-browser.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 Drag&Drop is not supported in Android Browser :
http://caniuse.com/#search=drag

You can use a third party js library to emulate that,
like jquery ui

but you have to add a plugin to enable drag&drop on mobile
this jquery ui plugin works great on Android browser : 
http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Have fun