# Can the save image menu in the android be disabled

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-ui

I have a container with draggable pictures (divs with img tags to be precise). The dragging and dropping works fine on desktop browsers, but on a android device holding your finger(without moving) over the item shows the save image menu, which breaks the drag functionality.
So can this menu be disabled, while the touch events are kept?

Comment: Android browser does not support drag and drop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670828/html5-drag-and-drop-in-android

Comment: It can support the jqueryui drag & drop if the touch/drag events are "translated" to mouseclick/mousemove. However it breaks, when pictures get involved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling the context menu on long taps on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413683/disabling-the-context-menu-on-long-taps-on-android)

Comment: That question doesn't include the "keeping the events" part. Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17618502/1165646) answer to it doesn't prevent the menu from appearing.